# Docker not installing Supervisor and crashing when it runs

Tags: laravel, docker, supervisord

I'm a touch new to Docker and Supervisor both, but I have a larvel application at work that needs three seperate queue workers run within it, so I figured a container with Supervisor would be a good idea... however, as much as the container goes up fine. It never seems to actually Install Supervisor. I shell into it and its missing. I can install it manually just fine, but then when I run my supervisord.config, I get a repeat of the same error and can't seem to figure out why... any advice would be appreciated!

Dockerfile;

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y supervisor && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  sed -i 's/^\(\[supervisord\]\)$/\1\nnodaemon=true/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

# Copy config file over
COPY /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

# Run Supervisor
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Supervisord.conf;

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
user=root
nodaemon=true
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:listen
directory=/tmp/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
stopwaitsecs=10800
```

I've removed the other two programs from the supervisord.conf for now until I get at least ONE of them working. The only difference is that the other two have a queue set in the command line for laravel.

Edit; Forgot to mention, the error I get from Supervisor is "exit status 1" three times, as is Supervisors apparent restart default, and then it fatal's out and stops.

Comment: Can you run the workers in separate containers, instead, without involving supervisord?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this! Turns out I had been accidentally running the supervisor container in the same image as all the apache stuff, so it was clashing quite spectacularly. I changed the container running supervisor to its own image in the docker-compose and it all clicked in suddenly!

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile, docker-compose.yml file and supervisor config of your application? Thank you